# Odoo/OpenERP: How can i restrict a user to his own journal entries

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I want to restrict a user so that he can only see his own journal entries, make edits to just his own entries etc. how can i do this. I tried but could not achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `res.group`, which the user will belong to.
Then you have to give to that group access in the `ir.model.access.csv` security file.
Now define a `ir.rule` with the attribute `domain_force` which takes a python coded condition, setting the permissions.
Like this:

```
<record id="user_see_its_own" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">User can see only its own records</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="< your_model >"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('*<your_group>*'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="0"/>
    <field name="domain_force">
        [('create_uid', '=', user.id)]
    </field>
</record>
```

And you're done.

Remember, if you have other groups above this particular one, you have to nullify the `ir.rule` just created defining one with an always true condition.
Like this:

```
<record id="manager_see_all" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Manager see all</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="< your_model >"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('*<your_group>*'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="1"/>
    <field name="domain_force">
        [(1, '=', 1)]
    </field>
</record>
```